# Strange results of google's indexing of my site

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a site named comehike.com which got hit by the panda update and I am trying to de-index some bad pages.

If I do this search in google: site:comehike.com/outdoors then I see about a 1000 results.

If I do this search in google: site:comehike.com/outdoors/ then I see about 6,000 results.

How can that be? The only difference is the slash at the end. If anything there should be less results or the same number.  No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL with a slash and a URL without a slash are not necessarily the same thing. As you've taken your site down we can't see what the difference is, but it looks like your site was set up to return different things for those different URLs.